# How can i use multiple lists as arguments in a function and receive them differently?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose, i have three lists,

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,3,4]
c = [4,5,6]
```

and receive them in a function:

```
def foo(x,y,z):
    """I will print or use x,y, and z differently"""

foo(a,b,c)
```

I come to know that i can pass a list using (*args) in Python:

```
foo(*x)
```

But here, x unpacks the items in every list and store them within itself.

I want my function to accept the lists separately in different arguments.

Comment: `foo(*x)` you can use it will have tuple of list, you can use ti from there

Comment: If `x` is `[1, 2, 3]`, `foo(*x)` is equivalent to `foo(1, 2, 3)`.  What do you expect `foo(*x, **y)` to be equivalent to?

Comment: And def fn(x, y, z) doesnt work because?

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry i was in a hurry so i couldn't express the question properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
def foo(*x):    # x will always will be tuple, whatever you pass
    """I will print or use x,y, and z differently"""
    for i in range(len(x)):   
        print(x[i])           # instead of printing, you can assign values
```

demo:

```
>>> foo([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[3,5,6,3])
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 5, 6, 3]
```

if you don't want to use range

```
>>> def foo(*x):
...     print(x)
...     for i in x:
...         print(i)
...
```

output:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [3, 5, 6, 3])  # you can see its tuple containing list
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 5, 6, 3]
```